# Web Deployment IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have not deployed websites before on an IIS7.  I was wondering if anyone could help me out to make sure that I am doing it right.  I have an ASP/C# website that I am trying to deploy.  The only access that I have to the server is through RDP.  No FTP or whatsoever.

I've read guides about different deployment options and none really talks about File System deployment which I think is my only option.

Basically I deploy the files locally to my laptop and I copy and paste it to the remote server.  I placed the compiled site to the \intepub\wwwroot and use the inetmgr to add that to the default site.  I did set the correct app pool to .net 4.0 since that's the framework that I used for the asp site.

I can access some of the components/pages of the site but unable to for some of them.  It's giving me errors but the one thing that I noticed is that the errors contains directory paths that refers to my laptop where I developed the site.  So, I'm assuming that I am not publishing the website correctly.

Comment: can you post those error messages?

Comment: Your assumption isn't necessarily correct - if you're seeing stack traces in asp.net error pages it's quite normal to see file paths from the build machine rather than the server the site is running on.

Comment: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ModuleOne.Pages.Faculty.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\School\Winter 2012\SYST34579\Deliverable 3\ModuleDeliverable3\ModuleDeliverable3\Faculty\FacultyOnly.aspx.cs:27

Comment: That's one of them.  I also noticed that the classes that I made are gone.  I don't see them inside the compiled site/deployed site.  Is this normal?  I'm using a method of a class to check for something on line 27 which might be why it's giving a nullreference exception.

Comment: You should post that exception with the code that it is pointing it to in your question.

Comment: @ReimarRobles - You need to post the code in the question, we can't see what line 27 is! :)

Comment: if (GetData.getTable().Rows.Count != 0) - Basically checks if there is something and if not then do something else.  I can connect to the MS SQL Server fine from my build machine.  I changed the connectionString to reflect the localhost\\instanceName but it won't connect locally after I compile the code.  So, it leads me to believe that the compiled code is fine but might be a problem of connectionString.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your returned table on the statement

```
if (GetData.getTable().Rows.Count != 0)
```

is `null`. This would throw the exception that you are getting. You can fix this by making sure your table object is an actual instance (assuming Datatable):

```
Datatable tbl = new Datatable();  //OK

Datatable tbl = null;   //Not OK
```

Also, you said the `NullReferenceException` was just one of them. Maybe that's not the root problem. You should have the part of the code that opens the connection and executes the query within a try/catch block, and if there is a problem there you can catch the error and know what is going wrong. If you can narrow down your problem, we can be more helpful.

Comment: That's the thing.  The getTable() returns a row on the build machine and I've set a static value for the query that I know is on the table for testing purposes.  So, I really think I'm missing something on the connectionString part. This is the connection string part on my build machine String connectionString = "Server=142.xx.xx.xx; Database=*******; User=*******; Password=******"; (Removed private info)

Comment: When I transfer the files on to the server, I change the connectionString appropriately to String connectionString = "Server=(local)\\instanceName; Database=*******; User=*******; Password=********";.